Portainer compose not working when local does
I am setting up a portainer server. I already installed and tested it with some prebuilt images from the registry.
I am trying to deploy an app consisting of a FastAPi back and a React front. There are no errors building and running the app. When I tell Portainer to pull and deploy, I get these errors:
Fastapi:
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using WatchFiles
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".

React:
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-plotly.js/react-plotly.js 8:37-69
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'plotly.js/dist/plotly' in 
'/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-plotly.js'
webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning

I already fixed the plotly error, installing it and pushing to remote. The package.json contains the plotly (and the local Docker compose deploy works).
These are the Dockerfiles and the Docker compose files:
Fastapi:
FROM python:3.11.5
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN cat /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload"]

React:
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]

Compose:
version: "3.8"

services:
  balancer:
    container_name: balancer
    build:
      context: ./balancer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./balancer/app:/app
    environment:
      - DOCKER_APP="true"
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=postgres
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_RESET=false
      - HOST_IP=192.168.1.120 # Reemplazar con tu IP actual

  front:
    container_name: front
    build:
      context: ./balancer-ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./balancer-ui:/app
    depends_on:
      - balancer
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_DOCKER_APP=true
      - REACT_APP_HOST_IP=192.168.1.120 # Reemplazar con tu IP actual

I tested it and it works locally on Windows and Fedora machines, but not in the Debian server.
Is there something I am missing? I can not get it to work. I also reinstalled Portainer but the plotly and main module problems are still appearing.
Thanks in advance

The volumes: blocks overwrite everything in your image, including the node_modules tree.  Does deleting them help?  (Your setup hints at a db PostgreSQL container, that should keep a volume mounted on /var/lib/postgresql/data.)
